# How to inject IL into a method at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, code-injection, il

Title more or less says it all. Based on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CLRMethodInjection.aspx) article, I've come up with this:

```
public static unsafe void Replace(this MethodBase destination, MethodBase source)
{
    IntPtr srcHandle = source.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
    IntPtr dstHandle = destination.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();

    int* dstPtr = (int*)dstHandle.ToPointer();
    *dstPtr = srcHandle.ToInt32();
}
```

This actually works... occasionally -.-

For example, this works.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo methodA = typeof(Program).GetMethod("A", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        MethodInfo methodB = typeof(Program).GetMethod("B", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        methodA.Replace(methodB);

        A();
        B();
    }

    public static void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hai World");
    }

    public static void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bai World");
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't (SEHException). All I did was change the order in which the functions were defined.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo methodA = typeof(Program).GetMethod("A", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        MethodInfo methodB = typeof(Program).GetMethod("B", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        methodA.Replace(methodB);

        A();
        B();
    }

    public static void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bai World");
    }

    public static void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hai World");
    }
}
```

As for the code in the article... I couldn't get it to work at all.

Any ideas/alternatives?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: Don't worry - nothing malicious. Just for the sake of knowledge :D

Comment: I believe that the only safe way to do this is to inject the code before the assembly is loaded.

Comment: @Porges, perhaps, but I think it wiser to assume this is never safe.  Ever.

Comment: its a good question. I wish there was an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is making a lot of bad assumptions which will bite you in the ass.

First things first, the structure returned via reflection is not guaranteed, in any way, to point to any runtime structures at all. As such attempting to modify the pointers it contains or returns is just plain wrong.

Secondly, if you wish to do something like injecting pre/post method call invariants (as an example) then you should probably construct runtime proxy objects and inject those instead. Or use dynamic method construction through the Emit namespace. Attempting to manipulate things through undocumented/unknown behaviors (such as the above code) just wont work.

You also need to realize that the JIT decides when it will run. Sometimes it runs against an entire class, and sometimes it just runs against a single method. Your code makes no attempt at determining if the method has been JITted yet, and blindly assumes that the function pointer returned can be modified.

Comment: In that case... a) So what exactly does it point to then? b) How do I figure out if a method has been JITted?

Comment: b) you can't, unless the program was processed through NGen before execution.

Comment: The simple answer is: You don't know what it points to. It is just a pointer, it has uses, but changing it is an undefined and error prone operation and should NEVER be done. You can tell if a method has been JITted through the use of the debugging interfaces. However, that still doesn't change the fact that the pointer is NOT something you should fiddle with.

Comment: So what should I be fiddling with instead?

Comment: Simply put: You don't change where methods points to at runtime. Ever. For instance, those two methods you have above would both be inlined usually by the JIT. As such, changing that pointer does no good, even if it did do what you and the original author (of the article) thought it did. If you want to do something where you can change which method is invoked at runtime, that's what delegates are for.